# Null parameter in OData Custom Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, parameters, odata

I want a custom action added in my OData controller for adding an entity. I can do that in standard Post method supplied in OData controller but I have some custom code that get's overwritten when I refresh the controller from database if I add an association.

Here is the custom method I've added

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult CreateValidCombination(ValidCombination validCombination)
{
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        return Ok();
}
```

The request header is same as the standard post method

```
POST http://localhost:20152/Admin/odata/ValidCombinations/fn.CreateValidCombination HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: http://localhost:20152/Admin/index.html
Accept-Language: en-CA,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like     Gecko
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 284
DNT: 1
Host: localhost:20152
Pragma: no-cache
```

The Action is configured in WebApiConfig.cs as

```
builder.EntityType<ValidCombination>().Collection
            .Action("CreateValidCombination")
            .Returns<IHttpActionResult>();
```

The problem is while the standard OData Contoller Post method receives the parameter of type "ValidCombination" proper, customer method receives it as null.

I've checked request headers and body in fiddler and its same in both the cases. I've even tried putting [FromBody] in front of the parameter but to no avail. I am trying to get value into the parameter for my custom method.

Has anyone faced this situation before. Is there a way I can debug why the parameter is not properly being deserialized even though request and body are same for both the methods?

Answer (score 0):

According to http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#04-07-action-parameter-support, in your customized action method, parameter type should be ODataActionParameters instead of ValidCombination, OData WebApi's code is in [github](https://github.com/OData/WebApi), is very easy to debug, you can find lots of function tests too.